# What information exactly does enctype="multipart/form-data" send to server?

Tags: php, upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to make a php script to upload files. From my understanding so far, `enctype="multipart/form-data"` sends certain type of header to http to make uploading file possible. Now what I don't know is what exactly those information are. Is there anyway I can echo or view that header file? Also, the reason that I am interested in this is because I wanted to edit(Add) some of the information in header.

Basically what I am going for is whenever a user selects a file from `<input type="file"/>` I want to append it in the header so that the information is saved (I will probably use session to store those information) and user can continue to select other files. I know there is `<input type="file" multiple/>` to select multiple files but the approach I am going for is a bit different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding so far, enctype="multipart/form-data" sends certain type of header to http to make uploading file possible.

Yes

> Also, the reason that I am interested in this is because I wanted to
>   edit(Add) some of the information in header.

Why? You cannot edit the header information until the request has arrived on your server. Then there is no point?

> Basically what I am going for is whenever a user selects a file from <
>   input type="file"/ > I want to append it in the header so that the
>   information is saved (I will probably use session to store those
>   information)

The data is only sent, when the `<form>` has been submitted, and then all the selected files are `POST`'ed

To allow an indefinite amount of files, you can use `<input type="file" name="attachment[]">` and use javascript to allow users to add attachments.

There are also plenty of very nice uploaders available;

- http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ (this is supposed to be a very good one)
- http://www.uploadify.com/

`<input type="file" multiple/>` is only supported by HTML5, so not recommended for usage yet.

Comment: _"Why? You cannot edit the header information until the request has arrived on your server. Then there is no point?"_
You're right. This never came across my mind. What I basically wanted to do was just create one of those "Attach a File" link in Gmail where whenever user adds another file the old file does not get overwritten by the new one.

Comment: Ok, you can do that with <input type="file">, but it won't look like on Gmail. See the links I posted for example tools for nice uploaders.

Comment: Ok I did manage to make it work on Firefox but Chrome and IE is giving me weird error. Here's my code, ignore the php codes for now and also the code is messy so yes ignore that too :D. http://pastebin.com/K76MANur
I'm still trying to make it work on Chrome and IE. I guess Chrome handles jquery.click() differently than Firefox and I don't even know what is wrong with IE.

Answer (score 0):

`multipart/form-data` is defined by [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578).